# VBA Userform Loading bar wont run untill window closed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I cant seem to work out why this wont work. I want for each A the label in the userform to increase the width.

But when i run it the rest of the sub wont run until the form is closed. How can i stop this??

```
    Sub movepost()

    Dim a As Range
    Dim rcount As Long
    Dim load As Variant

    Dim load1 As Variant
    Dim width As Variant

    width = fmLoadingBar.Label1.width

        For Each a In Range("a2:A9999")
            If a.Value = "" Then
            rcount = a.Row
            End If

        Next a

    DoEvents
    fmLoadingBar.Show


    rcount = (rcount - 1) * 12
    load = width / rcount
    fmLoadingBar.Label1.width = 0


        For Each a In Range("A2:l9999")

                If a.Column = 1 Then

                ElseIf a.Column = 6 Then
                ElseIf a.Column = 7 Then

                ElseIf a.Column = 11 Then

                ElseIf a.Value = "" Then

                    a.Value = a.Offset(0, -1).Value
                ElseIf a.Value = "" And a.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" And a.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" And a.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then

                    Exit For


                End If

            load1 = load1 + load

            fmLoadingBar.Label1.width = load1

        Next a
    Unload fmLoadingBar

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is shown without arguments, so it defaults to a modal form. You need a non-modal form, which means that the sub will continue without waiting for the form to unload. Try this:

```
fmLoadingBar.Show vbModeless
```

It is possible that the loop will not give the program (Excel) time to do other events then what you ask of it (for example draw graphics on the screen, or listen to mouse scrolls etc.). To let Excel 'look around' for other events to be executed while in the loop, you can use `DoEvents` within the loop. But beware, because it will cost you, performancewise. Test without it first.

Comment: What exactly does happen when you show the form modeless? Does the sub still waits for the form to close? You can try loading the form first,so before you show it. Simply `Load fmLoadingBar` .

Comment: The form displays / timer spins but no animation of the bar loading? I guess it should work. 

Load doesn't work this end. I have worked out something though, if i select another open window the bar loads as expected?

Comment: Oh, so the sub does work now. You can try redrawing the form in the loop, so after you set the width of bar you use fmLoadingBar.Redraw